# Unable to send messages to Kafka

Tags: apache-kafka

I created a kafka docker from [wurstmeisters docker image](https://github.com/wurstmeister/kafka-docker) and after that followed the steps 3, 4 and 5 from [apache documetnation](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/) to produce and consume messages. Unfortunately it is not possible to do so. 3 seconds after im sending a message I get the following error:

[image]

I cant find solutions for the given error. So what do I have to do to solve this issue?

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '2'
services:
  zookeeper:
    image: wurstmeister/zookeeper
    ports:
      - "2181:2181"
  kafka:
    build: .
    ports:
      - "9092:9092"
    environment:
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME: localhost
      KAFKA_CREATE_TOPICS: "test:1:1"
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: zookeeper:2181
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
```

**EDIT**

The zookeeper is reachable.

```
bin/kafka-topics.sh --list --zookeeper localhost:2181
```

returns:

```
baeldung
filtered
greeting
partitioned
test
```

So only the broker is not available.

Comment: Have you tried `--broker-list 120.0.0.1:9092` and `--broker-list 120.0.0.1:9092`? Also looking at https://github.com/wurstmeister/kafka-docker/issues/100 might be helpful.

Comment: why `120.0.0.1:9092` ? and also why two times the same command?

Comment: Or sorry should have said `--broker-list 127.0.0.1:9092` or `--broker-list 0.0.0.0:9092`

Comment: Both IP's deliver the same result as showing in my post.

Comment: Try giving advertised host name a name different than `localhost` that might be the issue. Rename it to some thing like `kafka` then add it to your `/etc/hosts` like such `127.0.0.1       localhost kafka.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion it is very strange but it seems that it was a simple conflict due to the version. The `kafka/wurstmeister` image is using Kafka Version `kafka_2.12-0.10.2.1.tgz` so ofcourse I downloaded the same version for the consumer and producer clients. That leaded to the result I posted above.

Now I tried the version `kafka_2.11-0.11.0.0.tgz` and everything is working fine. I thought the versions should match to work but obviously that is not the case.

Comment: The matched versions should work. Your problem must be something else.